# If no 3 diagonals of a convex decagon meet at the same point, inside the decagon. Into how many line segments are diagonals divided by their...

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, factorial

Question : If no 3 diagonals of a convex decagon meet at the same point, inside the decagon. Into how many line segments are diagonals divided by their intersections?

Answer : The no. of ways of selecting 2 vertices out of 10 vertices is : $C(10,2) = 45$.

10 sides, so the number of vertices is 45-10=35 **(why?-1)**

**(Why?-2)** The number of intersections $C(10,4) = 210$.

**(Why?-3)** The required number is = $35+420 = 455$

My misunderstandings are labelled as Why-1,2,3.

Please help me understanding this problem. There is a similar question already discussed here but that doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: In the first question, you use vertices to have a different meaning that the vertices of the decagon. What does it mean there?

Comment: I write exactly what was written in the lectures, I've no further clue present. @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Since for every 4 vertices we can count exactly 1 intersection between the diagonals so total number of intersections would be C(10 , 4) = 210 intersections between the diagonals  and also the number of diagonals would be C(10 , 2) -10 = 45 - 10 as there are C(10 , 2) straight lines joining the C(10 , 2) pairs of vertices ,but 10 of these 45 lines are the sides of the decagon.

Comment: The number of line segments are k+1 when there are k intersections along a line and each intersecting point lies on two diagonals.we start with 35 diagonals. Each intersection point adds a segment to both of the intersecting diagonals. Therefore the total number of straight line segments into which the diagonals are divided is answer is 35 + twice number of intersections.
 $= 35+2×210$.

Comment: I didn't understand the first line "The number of line segments are k+1 when there are k intersections along a line and each intersecting point lies on two diagonals." Can you please explain a bit more? @JitendraSingh

Comment: Read the message in continuation. My first message + second message is the answer of the originall question

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice the first part before. @JitendraSingh

Answer (score 1):

1. They have a typo here; they meant to say that the number of **diagonals** is $45-10=35$. There are $45$ line segments in the picture, but $10$ of these are the sides of the decagon, so there are $35$ diagonals left over.
2. An intersection point is uniquely determined by choosing $4$ vertices out of the ten decagon vertices. These four vertices define a quadrilateral, and the two diagonals of that quadrilateral are also diagonals of the decagon. The intersection of the two diagonals are an intersection point.
3. This is the tricky part. Think about this; if you have a string, and you cut it at $k$ places, then you have $k+1$ pieces of string. That is, each cut adds a piece. Therefore, to count the number of pieces the diagonals are cut into, you take the number of diagonals, $35$, and you add the number of cuts, which is the number of intersection points, $420$.